# What's the easiest way to calculate regression coefficient in python?

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have a 100 by 1 response variable Y, and a 100 by 3 predictor matrix X. I want to calcualte the regression coefficient (X'X)^{-1}X'Y.

Currently I'm doing it as follows:

```
invXpX=inv(np.dot(np.transpose(X),X))
XpY=np.dot(np.transpose(X),Y)
betahat=np.dot(invXpX,XpY)
```

This looks pretty cumbersome, while in MATLAB we could do it just like the original math formula: inv(X'*X)*X'*Y.  Is there an easier way to calculate this regression coefficient in python?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be written more compact, but note that this will not always improve your code, or the readability.

The transpose of a numpy array can be found using dot T (`.T`). If you use numpy matrix instead of numpy arrays you can also use `.I` for the inverse, but I would recommend you to use ndarray. For the dot product you can use `@`. Thereby `np.dot(X,Y) = X.dot(Y)` when `X` and `Y` are numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np
# Simulate data using a quadratic equation with coefficients y=ax^2+bx+c 
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
x = np.arange(100)
# Add random component to y values for estimation
y = a*x**2 + b*x + c + np.random.randn(100)
# Get X matrix [100x3]
X = np.vstack([x**2, x, np.ones(x.shape)]).T

# Estimate coefficients a, b, c
x_hat = np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)
>>> array([0.99998334, 2.00246583, 2.95697339])
x_hat = np.linalg.inv(X.T@(X))@(X.T)@(y)
>>> array([0.99998334, 2.00246583, 2.95697339])

# Use matrix:
X_mat = np.matrix(X)
x_hat = (X_mat.T@X_mat).I@X_mat.T@y
>>> matrix([[0.99998334, 2.00246583, 2.95697339]])

# without noise:
y = a*x**2 + b*x + c 
x_hat = (X_mat.T@X_mat).I@X_mat.T@y
>>> matrix([[1., 2., 3.]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This completely solves my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
np.invert(X.T @ X) @ (X.T @ Y)
```